# Looping over sampling in R to create many vectors

Tags: r, pca

I am doing some PCA analysis using the following R code:

```
sigma1 <- as.matrix((data[,3:22]))
sigma2 <- as.matrix((data[,23:42]))
sample1 <- mvrnorm(n = 250, mu = as_vector(data[,1]), Sigma = sigma1)
sample2 <- mvrnorm(n = 250, mu = as_vector(data[,2]), Sigma = sigma2)
sampCombined <- rbind(sample1, sample2);
covCombined <- cov(sampCombined);
covCombinedPCA <- prcomp(sampCombined);
eigenvalues <- covCombinedPCA$sdev^2;
```

I want to repeat/loop this, so that I have 50 vectors of eigenvalues. I then want to find the mean vector of eigenvalues over the 50 repetitions. How do I do this?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Not my downvote but I guess the reason for downvote is lack of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your entire code in a function. Let's say the function is called `eigen_fun`.

```
eigen_fun <- function(data) {
  sigma1 <- as.matrix((data[,3:22]))
  sigma2 <- as.matrix((data[,23:42]))
  sample1 <- mvrnorm(n = 250, mu = as_vector(data[,1]), Sigma = sigma1)
  sample2 <- mvrnorm(n = 250, mu = as_vector(data[,2]), Sigma = sigma2)
  sampCombined <- rbind(sample1, sample2);
  covCombined <- cov(sampCombined);
  covCombinedPCA <- prcomp(sampCombined);
  eigenvalues <- covCombinedPCA$sdev^2;
  return(eigenvalues)
}
```

Running `eigen_fun(data)` once gives you one set of values. To repeat this 50 times, you can use `replicate`.

```
mat <- replicate(50, eigen_fun(data))
```

Every column in `mat` is one set of value, to get `mean` of each iteration you can use `colMeans` :

```
colMeans(mat)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So put it in the curly bracket `eigen_fun() {}`? I get `Error: unexpected '{' in "eigen_fun() {"`

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! Out of curiosity, is the entire code supposed to go in the function? Or is it supposed to be just the part after the sample generation? I'm not sure which one makes sense.

Comment: You can take out first 2 lines i.e `sigma1` and `sigma2` part out of the function since that is going to be the same. Rest all needs to be in the function.

Comment: So the result doesn't change either way?

Comment: Yes, the result would be the same.